# Optimize SQL Query with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with a query running slow when using group by:

```
SELECT           `customers`.`id` 
                ,`customers`.`firstname`
                ,`customers`.`lastname`
                ,`customers`.`address`
                ,`customers`.`address_co`
                ,`customers`.`country`
                ,`customers`.`zipcode`
                ,`customers`.`city`
                ,`customers`.`phone`
                ,`customers`.`mobilephone`
                ,`customers`.`ssn`
                ,`users`.`email`
                ,`customer_lists`.`name`        AS `customerList`
                ,COUNT( transactions.id )       AS transactions_count
                ,SUM( transactions.sum_incl )   AS sum_incl
                ,SUM( transactions.sum_excl )   AS sum_excl
                ,`customers`.`created_at` 
FROM            `customers` 
INNER JOIN      `users` 
ON              `customers`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN       `transactions` 
ON              `customers`.`id` = `transactions`.`customer_id` 
INNER JOIN      `customer_lists`
ON              `customers`.`customer_list_id` = `customer_lists`.`id` 
WHERE           `customer_lists`.`club_id` =  '1'
GROUP BY        `customers`.`id` 
ORDER BY        `customers`.`created_at` DESC
```

When I run a `EXPLAIN` it says `Using temporary; Using filesort`.

```
**id**  **select_type** **table**       **type**    **possible_keys**                                       **key**                             **key_len** **ref**                             **rows**    **Extra**
1       SIMPLE          customer_lists  ref         PRIMARY,club_id_index                                   club_id_index                       8           const                               1           Using temporary; Using filesort
1       SIMPLE          customers       ref         customers_user_id_foreign,customers_customer_list_...   customers_customer_list_id_index    8           kund_workbox_nu.customer_lists.id   867  
1       SIMPLE          users           eq_ref      PRIMARY                                                 PRIMARY                             8           kund_workbox_nu.customers.user_id   1    
1       SIMPLE          transactions    ref         customer_id_index                                       customer_id_index                   8           kund_workbox_nu.customers.id        3108
```

How do I fix that?

## UPDATE

### Tables:

#### Customers

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `customer_list_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `address_co` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `zipcode` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `mobilephone` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ssn` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_login` datetime NOT NULL,
  `added_information` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `customers_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
  KEY `customers_customer_list_id_index` (`customer_list_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `customers_customer_list_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_list_id`) REFERENCES `customer_lists` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `customers_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29739 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

#### Transactions

```
CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `transaction_type_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `sum_incl` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL,
  `sum_excl` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `transactions_customer_id_foreign` (`customer_id`),
  KEY `transactions_transaction_type_id_foreign` (`transaction_type_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `transactions_customer_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customers` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `transactions_transaction_type_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`transaction_type_id`) REFERENCES `transaction_types` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=580116 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

#### Customer Lists

```
CREATE TABLE `customer_lists` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `club_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(90) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `customer_lists_club_id_foreign` (`club_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `customer_lists_club_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`club_id`) REFERENCES `clubs` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: What is the explain plan without the `group by`? Your question has no information on the expected behavior or your definition of 'slow'.

Comment: The query takes 3883 ms and I'm expecting much faster and taught it has something to do with `Using temporary; Using filesort`

Comment: If you want to make a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and put some sample data in the tables, I'd be willing to try to help, but its hard to judge performance on an unfamiliar query with no dataset to test against

Comment: I don't think 3883ms was slow if your transactions table was the largest table, and you filter it only use customer_id. Suggest you can filter transactions table with some other conditions such as `create_at` date .

Comment: It may be better to move customer_lists to a subquery - e.g. `INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, Name FROM customer_lists WHERE club_id = '1') AS cl ON ...` - The reason is that it appears there is only one row that matches this in `customer_lists`, so materializing this one row into a hashed table at the start of execution (which is what MySQL does with subqueries) should be beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try a single table grouping on transactions as a derived table?

```
SELECT
      `customers`.`id`
    , `customers`.`firstname`
    , `customers`.`lastname`
    , `customers`.`address`
    , `customers`.`address_co`
    , `customers`.`country`
    , `customers`.`zipcode`
    , `customers`.`city`
    , `customers`.`phone`
    , `customers`.`mobilephone`
    , `customers`.`ssn`
    , `users`.`email`
    , `customer_lists`.`name` AS `customerList`
    , `trans`.transactions_count
    , `trans`.sum_incl
    , `trans`.sum_excl
    , `customers`.`created_at`
FROM `customers`
INNER JOIN `users` ON `customers`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
INNER JOIN `customer_lists` ON `customers`.`customer_list_id` = `customer_lists`.`id`
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
          `transactions`.`customer_id`
        , COUNT(transactions.id) AS transactions_count
        , SUM(transactions.sum_incl) AS sum_incl
        , SUM(transactions.sum_excl) AS sum_excl
    FROM `transactions`
    GROUP BY `transactions`.`customer_id`
    ) `trans` ON `customers`.`id` = `trans`.`customer_id`
WHERE `customer_lists`.`club_id` = '1'
ORDER BY `customers`.`created_at` DESC
```

A where clause in that subquery may also help.

Comment: The query took ~`2066 ms` instead of ~`3883 ms`, so absolutely an improvement! But I still get `Using temporary; Using filesort`

Comment: if you remove the final `order by` do you still see filesort?

Comment: I suggest you read the answer here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44614/is-it-possible-to-avoid-filesort do you have an index on `customers`.`created_at` ? that MIGHT work to avoid the filesort

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create indexes on all the JOIN columns, i.e. `customers`.`user_id`,  `users`.`id`, `transactions`.`customer_id`, ... ?